# Images not uploading in Database Rails 5 | Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, paperclip, activescaffold

I'm unable to upload an image in my nested scaffold form.

All other fields are getting in the database except the image. Please help!

I am on rails 5.2 and using paperclip for image uploading and images need to be uploaded on AWS.

I am not getting any errors its just the images are not entering the database.

Thanks!

**Controller**

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_campaign, except: [:your_posts]
  before_action :set_content, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :approve, :decline]

  # GET campaigns/1/contents
  def index
    @contents = @campaign.contents
  end

  # GET campaigns/1/contents/1
  def show
  end

  # GET campaigns/1/contents/new
  def new
    @content = @campaign.contents.build
  end

  # GET campaigns/1/contents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST campaigns/1/contents
  def create
    if !current_user.is_active_influencer
      return redirect_to payout_method_path, alert: "Please Connect to Stripe Express first."
    end

    campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
    if campaign.active == false
      flash[:alert] = "This Campaign is closed"
    elsif current_user == campaign.user
      flash[:alert] = "You cannot apply for your own campaign!"
    elsif
      @content = current_user.contents.build(content_params)
      @content.campaign = campaign
      @content.transaction_fee = @content.price * 15/100
      @content.total = @content.price + @content.transaction_fee
      @content.save

      flash[:notice] = "Applied Successfully!"
    end
    redirect_to campaign
  end

  # PUT campaigns/1/contents/1
  def update
    if @content.update_attributes(content_params)
      redirect_to([@content.campaign, @content], notice: 'Content was successfully updated.')
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE campaigns/1/contents/1
  def destroy
    @content.destroy
    redirect_to campaign_contents_url(@campaign)
  end

  def your_posts
    @posts = current_user.contents
  end

  def approve
    if current_user.stripe_id.blank?
      flash[:alert] = "Please update your payment method."
      return redirect_to payment_method_path
    elsif
      charge(@campaign, @content)
    elsif
      flash[:alert] = "Cannot make a reservation!"
    end
  end

  def decline
    @content.Declined!
    redirect_to campaign_contents_path
  end

  private

  #Twilio_start
  def send_sms(campaign, content)
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new
    @client.messages.create(
      from: '+18646060816',
      to: content.user.phone_number,
      body: "You content for '#{campaign.brand_name}' has been approved."
    )
  end
  #Twilio_end

  def charge(campaign, content)
    if !campaign.user.stripe_id.blank?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(campaign.user.stripe_id)
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => content.total * 100,
        :description => campaign.name,
        :currency => "usd",
        :destination => {
          :amount => content.price * 95, # 95% of the content amount goes to the Content Maker
          :account => content.user.merchant_id # Influencer's Stripe customer ID
        }
      )

      if charge
        content.Approved!
        ContentMailer.send_email_to_influencer(content.user, campaign).deliver_later if content.user.setting.enable_email
        send_sms(campaign, content) if content.user.setting.enable_sms #Twilio
        flash[:notice] = "Paid and Approved successfully!"
        redirect_to campaign_contents_path
      else
        reservation.Declined!
        flash[:alert] = "Cannot charge with this payment method!"
      end
    end
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    content.Declined!
    flash[:alert] = e.message
  end

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_campaign
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
  end

  def set_content
    @content = @campaign.contents.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def content_params
    params.require(:content).permit(:post_copy, :is_facebook, :is_instagram, :is_twitter, :is_youtube, :price, :images)
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {Waiting: 0, Approved: 1, Declined: 2}

  after_create_commit :create_notification

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :campaign

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  private

  def create_notification
    type = self.campaign.Instant? ? "New Booking" : "New Request"
    influencer = User.find(self.user_id)

    Notification.create(content: "#{type} from #{influencer.fullname}", user_id: self.campaign.user_id)
  end
end
```

**Views**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <span><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="color: #ffb400"></i> Apply for this campaign</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

<%= form_for([@campaign, @campaign.contents.new]) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Post Copy</label>
    <%= f.text_area :post_copy, rows: 5, placeholder: "Create your post exactly as you'd like to see it published.", class: "form-control", required: true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Price USD</label>
    <%= f.text_field :price, placeholder: "How much you will charge", class: "form-control", required: true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file text-babu">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Select Photos
      <%= f.file_field "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Where will you post?</label>
  </div>

  <% if !@campaign.facebook.blank? %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.check_box :is_facebook %> Facebook
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if !@campaign.twitter.blank? %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.check_box :is_twitter %> Twitter
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if !@campaign.instagram.blank? %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.check_box :is_instagram %> Instagram
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if !@campaign.youtube.blank? %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.check_box :is_youtube %> Youtube
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<br/>
<%= f.submit "Submit for Approval", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

**Terminal Response**

```
Started POST "/campaigns/1/contents" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 12:46:35 +0530
Processing by ContentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SavnYHjl5BHdUQXu4hVeyKHGgTgz7bfxXavDG8mKO2S1W0vfvjDn9RptHGJSBin/a0Gc2b7AfgzLY2eq2OpIRA==", "content"=>{"post_copy"=>"Test 5", "price"=>"10", "images"=>[], "is_facebook"=>"1", "is_instagram"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit for Approval", "campaign_id"=>"1"}
  Campaign Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:126
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:25
  CACHE Campaign Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:29
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:32
Unpermitted parameter: :images
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:39
  Content Create (3.2ms)  INSERT INTO "contents" ("user_id", "campaign_id", "post_copy", "is_facebook", "is_instagram", "price", "transaction_fee", "total", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 2], ["campaign_id", 1], ["post_copy", "Test 5"], ["is_facebook", 1], ["is_instagram", 1], ["price", 10], ["transaction_fee", 1], ["total", 11], ["created_at", "2018-10-18 07:16:35.409569"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-18 07:16:35.409569"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:39
   (11.4ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:39
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/content.rb:16
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/content.rb:18
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/content.rb:18
  Notification Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "New Request from Influencer"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-10-18 07:16:35.443967"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-18 07:16:35.443967"]]
  ↳ app/models/content.rb:18
   (3.1ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/models/content.rb:18
[ActiveJob] Enqueued NotificationJob (Job ID: dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fbe15387ec8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://Notification/5>>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/campaigns/1
Completed 302 Found in 60ms (ActiveRecord: 20.1ms)


  Notification Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/peeyushverma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5] Performing NotificationJob (Job ID: dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5) from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fbe15346478 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://Notification/5>>
Started GET "/campaigns/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 12:46:35 +0530
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5]   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5]   ↳ app/jobs/notification_job.rb:5
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5]   User Update All (1.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "unread" = COALESCE("unread", 0) + 1 WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5]   ↳ app/jobs/notification_job.rb:5
Processing by CampaignsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Campaign Load (7.5ms)  SELECT  "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5]   Rendered notifications/_notification.html.erb (1.7ms)
  ↳ app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:69
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to notification_1: {:message=>"<div class=\"panel\">\n  <div class=\"panel-body\">\n    <strong>New Request from Influencer</strong>\n    <span class=\"pull-right\">18 Oct 07:16</span>\n  </div>\n</div>\n", :unread=>2}
[ActiveJob] [NotificationJob] [dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5] Performed NotificationJob (Job ID: dd4f41ce-9428-49b5-9d29-8ec67c2bb4a5) from Async(default) in 76.89ms
NotificationsChannel transmitting {"message"=>"<div class=\"panel\">\n  <div class=\"panel-body\">\n    <strong>New Request from Influencer</strong>\n    <span class=\"pull-right\">18 Oct 07:16</span>\n  </div>\n</div>\n", "unread"=>2} (via streamed from notification_1)
  Rendering campaigns/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Photo Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."campaign_id" = ?  [["campaign_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/campaign.rb:19
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/campaigns/show.html.erb:20
  Campaign Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  campaigns.*, (111.19492664455873 * ABS(campaigns.latitude - 22.3511148) * 0.7071067811865475) + (96.29763124613503 * ABS(campaigns.longitude - 78.6677428) * 0.7071067811865475) AS distance, CASE WHEN (campaigns.latitude >= 22.3511148 AND campaigns.longitude >= 78.6677428) THEN  45.0 WHEN (campaigns.latitude <  22.3511148 AND campaigns.longitude >= 78.6677428) THEN 135.0 WHEN (campaigns.latitude <  22.3511148 AND campaigns.longitude <  78.6677428) THEN 225.0 WHEN (campaigns.latitude >= 22.3511148 AND campaigns.longitude <  78.6677428) THEN 315.0 END AS bearing FROM "campaigns" WHERE (campaigns.latitude BETWEEN 22.26118263940813 AND 22.441046960591873 AND campaigns.longitude BETWEEN 78.57050526395783 AND 78.76498033604217 AND campaigns.id != 1) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 3]]
  ↳ app/views/campaigns/show.html.erb:149
  Rendered contents/_form.html.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered campaigns/show.html.erb within layouts/application (32.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (1.2ms)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/shared/_navbar.html.erb:23
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (7.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 378ms (Views: 326.5ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)


Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 12:46:35 +0530
MessagesChannel stopped streaming from conversation_
NotificationsChannel stopped streaming from notification_2
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 12:46:36 +0530
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-18 12:46:36 +0530
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
MessagesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
MessagesChannel is streaming from conversation_
NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
NotificationsChannel is streaming from notification_2
```

Comment: can you show the parameters of the request and also try changing your permit parameters to this: 
    `params.require(:content).permit(:post_copy, :is_facebook, :is_instagram, :is_twitter, :is_youtube, :price, images: [])`

Comment: I have added the terminal response above.

Comment: I have aslo tried to change the params as mentioned by you but then I get an error  that is: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in ContentsController#create
unknown attribute 'images' for Content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model, you have:

```
has_attached_file :image
```

So I am assuming, Every Content has only one Image attached with it, but in you form in views, you are uploading multiple images as an array.

```
<%= f.file_field "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

Change this to:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

Also, in you ContentController, in content_params action, change :images param to :image

```
params.require(:content).permit(:post_copy, :is_facebook, :is_instagram, :is_twitter, :is_youtube, :price, :image)
```

**But,** if you want attach multiple images then you have to change the approach entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To have [paperclip](https://railsguide.org/gems/paperclip) supported uploading to s3, you need to add [gem "aws-sdk-s3"](https://railsguide.org/gems/aws-sdk-s3) to Gemfile file? And set [`s3_credentials`](https://railsguide.org/rails/Rails::AppBuilder/credentials) in model

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  #
  # rest of codes
  ###


        has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }        ,
                            :storage => :s3,
                            :s3_credentials => {
                              :bucket => "xxx", 
                              :access_key_id => "xxx", 
                              :secret_access_key => "xxx"}
        #rest of code


end
```

FYI https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Comment: Hi I have another model for uploading campaign images they are uploagin in s3 properly. I have these s3 credential in my development.rb file.